# Problems to pdf with dompdf library

Tags: php, css, laravel

I'm currently utilizing Laravel 5.5 in conjunction with the DomPDF library. My objective is to generate a printed representation of the following array:

```
$datas = [["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Bruno Santos Henriquez","Solteiro",null,"410.371.242-27","000041037142427","Pai: Vinícius Hall Henriquez - Mãe: Marli Goulart Santos","","",""],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Lurdes Junior Carmoriz","Solteiro",null,"852.668.377-21","000085266837721","Pai: Everton Meyer Carmoriz - Mãe: Manuela Coutinho Junior","","",""],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Thayline Guzzo Mendes","União Estável",null,"456.630.687-91","000045663068791","Pai: Otavio Simoes Mendes - Mãe: Marcy Cardoso Guzzo","Igor André Nelson dos Santos","606.363.690-05","606363690050555"],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Adão Cavalcanti Batista","Solteiro",null,"798.914.867-61","125905577580009","Pai:  - Mãe: Nelma Carminatti Cavalcanti","","",""],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Camila Kamilly Bruna Camposaad","Casado","Comunhão parcial de bens","437.745.820-50","437745820505050","Pai:  - Mãe: Marli Fernanda Isabel","Camila Clarice Almeida","811.395.702-26","43.548.827"],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Igor André Nelson dos Santos","União Estável",null,"606.363.690-05","606363690050555","Pai:  - Mãe: Benedita Clarice","Thayline Guzzo Mendes","456.630.687-91","000045663068791"],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Benício Erick Julio Figueiredo","Casado","Participação final nos aquestos","900.021.597-83","21.975.393","Pai: Bento Ryan Kaique Figueiredo - Mãe: Stella Clarice Benedita","Benedita Louise dos Santos","441.140.991-74","48.051.086"],
                      ["600","5","Reurb-S","Legitimação Fundiária","Rua Mato Grosso, nº 950 - Centro, Mata Verde - MG, 35118-000","Ruína","Samuel e Erick Eletrônica ME","","","42.987.281/0001-68","","","","",""],
                      ["7","2","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Maria Luiza Vargas Siqueira","Casado","Comunhão universal ou total de bens","153.901.933-00","237186317","Pai:  - Mãe: Tatiane Barthon Vargas","Reginaldo Montilla Nobrega","481.112.439-10","345806384"],
                      ["7","2","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Reginaldo Montilla Nobrega","Casado","Comunhão universal ou total de bens","481.112.439-10","345806384","Pai:  - Mãe: Dalva Barrada Montilla","Maria Luiza Vargas Siqueira","153.901.933-00","237186317"],
                      ["7","2","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Marilena Coutinho Vasconcellos","União Estável",null,"662.537.411-36","214608128","Pai:  - Mãe: Genilda Souza Coutinho","Rinaldo Barros Monnerat","515.758.577-23","177763322"],
                      ["7","2","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Rinaldo Barros Monnerat","União Estável",null,"515.758.577-23","177763322","Pai:  - Mãe: Jacqueline Dantas Barros","Marilena Coutinho Vasconcellos","662.537.411-36","214608128"],
                      ["7","2","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Luzineide Salomão Bezerra","Solteiro",null,"681.076.171-34","478250812","Pai:  - Mãe: Elisângela Barsosa Salomão","","",""],
                      ["6","10","Reurb-E","Legitimação de Posse","Saco Quadra A1, nº 767 - Portal da Alegria, Mata Verde - MT, 77006-412","Vago","Wescley Vilar Mourão","Solteiro",null,"310.035.151-77","392633188","Pai:  - Mãe: Ivania Vabo Vilar","","",""],
                      ["08","09","Reurb-E","Legitimação Fundiária","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Rebeca Rodrigues Camacho","Solteiro",null,"048.033.842-66","354532388","Pai:  - Mãe: Maria teste dois","","",""],
                      ["08","09","Reurb-E","Legitimação Fundiária","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Everton de Arruda Kuster","Solteiro",null,"512.542.891-43","232521347","Pai:  - Mãe: Kamily Machado de Arruda","","",""],
                      ["08","09","Reurb-E","Legitimação Fundiária","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Casemiro Anastacio Germano Bernardes","","","26.716.357/0001-64","","","","",""],
                      ["08","09","Reurb-E","Legitimação Fundiária","Alagado Campo Alegre, nº 89 - Tancredo Neves, Manaus - AM, 69087-674","Garagem","Theo Araujo Albenaz Rangel","","","26.287.601/0001-10","","","","",""],
                      ["1000","1","Nenhum","Legitimação de Posse","2ª Travessa da Avenida Tiê, nº 34 - Novo Horizonte, Mata Verde - ES, 29163-364","Residencial","Aparecida Gouveia Vargas","Solteiro",null,"887.247.586-47","383175331","Pai:  - Mãe: Aparecida Gouveia Vargas","","",""]
                    ];
```

In general, I am encountering some issues with page breaks, as illustrated in the image:
[image: dompdf]

This is my CSS code:

```
        @page {
            margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .table-no-border {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .table-no-border tr, .table-no-border th, .table-no-border td {
            border: none;
        }

        .table-border {
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .table-border tr, .table-border td {
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        #header {
            position: relative;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 94.5px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: -20px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 150px;
        }
```

and This is my PHP code:

```
@foreach($datas as $index => $requerimento)
                <tr>
                    @for($j = 0; $j < count($requerimento); $j++)
                        @php
                        $values = array_slice($requerimento, 0, 5);
                        $value = $requerimento[$j];
                        if ($index > 0 && array_slice($datas[$index - 1], 0, 5) === $values && $j < 6) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $rowspan = 1;
                        for ($k = $index + 1; $k < count($datas); $k++) {
                            if (array_slice($datas[$k], 0, 5) === $values && $j < 6) {
                                $rowspan++;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        @endphp
                        @if ($rowspan > 1) 
                            <td rowspan=" {{ $rowspan }}" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;"> {{ $value }}</td>
                        @else
                            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;"> {{ $value }} </td>
                        @endif
                    @endfor
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please take some time to create a [mre]. The PHP seems irrelevant here: if you are creating a PDF from HTML your question should show the HTML. Also your question does not explain what the problem is?